# How to handle XML in Java retrieving data from an xml database

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm using eXist-db within my java web application (mvc paradigm).
I want to retrieve xml data from the database, then transform this xml with a XSLT transformation. Here are the steps I go through.

1. I query the database and I get an `XMLResource`, or a `ResourceSet` as result.
2. Now I've got to transform the XML I retrieved from the database (as XMLResource) with a XSLT transformation.

   Since XSLT transformations (using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`) need a xml Source as parameter, I've got to **convert from XMLResource to StreamSource**.

But is this the best way to handle an xml resource? Should I convert my XMLResource in something else instead?

Answer (score 1):

`XMLResource` provides a [`getContentAsSAX` method](http://xmldb.exist-db.org/javadoc/org/xmldb/api/modules/XMLResource.html#getContentAsSAX%28org.xml.sax.ContentHandler%29) to feed the XML directly to a SAX ContentHandler.  And javax.xml.transform provides the concept of a [`TransformerHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/TransformerHandler.html), exposing a Transformer as a SAX ContentHandler.  So you can use these two in combination:

```
Source stylesheet = ... // however you're loading your stylesheet
TransformerHandler handler = ((SAXTransformerFactory)transformerFactory)
                              .newTransformerHandler(stylesheet);
Result result = ... // StreamResult, DOMResult etc.
handler.setResult(result);
xmlResource.getContentAsSAX(handler);

// result now holds the result of the transformation
```

For the reverse direction, if you need an `XMLResource` to act as the *target* of a transformation, then you can use `SAXResult` with a normal `Transformer`

```
Source stylesheet = ... // however you're loading your stylesheet
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(stylesheet);
Source source = ... // StreamSource, DOMSource, etc.
Result result = new SAXResult(xmlResource.setContentAsSAX());
transformer.transform(source, result);
```